# To be elaborated + on

Tags: grammar

As you are well aware, the intransitive verb "[elaborate](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/elaborate)" is followed by the preposition "on". Accordingly, I would be appreciative if you do me a favor and let me know whether the preposition is required in the following sentence or not. If not, then why?

> - This point will be elaborated further in the next chapter. [Source](https://sentencedict.com/elaborated.html)

Logically, the verb "elaborate" should take that preposition and I have no idea why the example has not been included by that?!
To me the correct version of the example would be:

> - This point will be elaborated ***on*** further in the next chapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> elaborate, elaborate on
>
> The transitive verb elaborate means to develop, produce or work out.
>
> The working group gradually elaborated its plans for rebuilding the
> town centre. When the verb elaborate is used intransitively, it is
> followed by the preposition on. The phrasal verb elaborate on refers
> to providing more details about a matter or topic.
>
> Ming offered a few tantalizing details but would not elaborate on the
> new venture.
>
> [BtB -
> Canada](https://www.btb.termiumplus.gc.ca/tpv2guides/guides/wrtps/index-eng.html?lang=eng&lettr=indx_catlog_e&page=9u5vwOzbRLK4.html#:%7E:text=The%20transitive%20verb%20elaborate%20means%20to%20develop%2C%20produce,providing%20more%20details%20about%20a%20matter%20or%20topic)

"Elaborate" can be transitive or intransitive.  The intransitive version requires "on".

If you elaborate something, you **extend** it or make it more complex. If you elaborate *on* something you **discuss** it in more detail.

**Answer**

On balance I prefer your version over the original.

Comment: Therefore, the correct version would be "This point will be elaborated **on** in the next chapter."

Comment: It's difficult to say in this case. You could either say, "This point will be expanded ..." or, "This point will be discussed in more detail ...".  Both make sense but my feeling is that the point (whatever it is) will be discussed in more detail in the next chapter - i.e.  it will be elaborated on. I think we would have to know more about the point and more about the next chapter to be certain.

Comment: I'm a bit confused now.  May I ask you to elaborate on your point? What is exactly wrong with: "This point will be elaborated on in the next chapter." Is it a matter of using two prepositions "on" and "in" in a row?

Comment: @A-friend  -  There is nothing wrong with it or the number of prepositions. I'm just saying that someone could make a *case* for omitting the "on".  I personally prefer "on" **in this particular context.**